# How to find the distance between two lines without any points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Let the first line $L_1=\langle 2-t, 2t,1+t\rangle$.
>
> The second line $L_2$ is the intersection of two planes: $x+y−z+1=0$ and $5x+2y+z−16=0$. Find the distance between the lines.

First we need to find the equation of $L_2$. This can be done by taking cross product of the normal vectors of the two planes:
$$
\langle 1,1,-1\rangle\times\langle5,2,1\rangle=\langle1,-2,-1\rangle
$$ 
Now we need to find a point on $L_2$. Let $z=0$ then we get a system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=-1\\5x+2y=16
\end{cases}\implies x=8/3, y=-11/3
$$
So $L_2=(8/3,-11/3,0)+\langle 1,-2,-1\rangle$.
The problem is that I checked online and the line is not the intersection ($L_2$ is the black dotted line):

[image]

Is my method not good?

Comment: The cross product is wrong and for the sake of easier calculations, I would take another point on $L_2$, e.g. $(0,5,6)$.

Comment: @StackTD sorry, typo

Comment: @StackTD Yes, it's wrong, but that's irrelevant, since the OP got $(1,-2,-1)$, the result is $(3,-6,-3)$ and what matters here is the direction of $L_2$.

Comment: You solved the linear system incorrectly.  $(\frac 83,-\frac {11}3)$ does not satisfy $5x+2y=16$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OP edited it, but when I made the comment there was a sign mistake too (not just the scalar multiple).

Comment: Just to say:  I'd have said that the easiest way to get the equation for $L_2$ was to find two points on it.  You already have one (well, if you solve the system correctly you will get $(6,-7,0)$ as one point).  To get another let $x=0$.

Comment: @lulu thank you, this was the mistake!

Comment: @lulu and if I wanted to compute the distance between the lines I could choose two random points (one point on one line and the other point on the second line), then get a vector between those points. Then I could find the projection of the vector onto one of the lines and then get the distance from Pythagoras theorem right?

Comment: As you use a calculus tag, I'd do it that way.  Pick a point on $L_1$ (with parameter $t$ ) and find the closest point to it on $L_2$.    Then minimize over $t$.  (note:  for problems like these it is often easier to work with the square of distance).

Comment: Nice tip, I didn't think about this as optimization problem